# Is there a way to draw bussproof style tree diagram in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, abstract-syntax-tree

An example of bussproof style tree diagram is shown below.

[image]

Above diagram shows the AST(abstract syntax tree) of the propositional formula $\neg A \to (B \vee C)$. Such a diagram can be drawn using the LaTeX package `bussproof.sty`.

I am aware that I could use `graphviz` for drawing AST, but somehow I prefer the simple bussproof style diagram. So here is my question: is there a way to draw bussproof style tree diagram for logical formulas and/or Natural deduction proof in Jupyter Notebook?

I tried graphviz, `treelib`, and `plotly`. None of these were satisfactory. I want bussproof style diagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a Python script that generates busproof-style tree diagrams. This script is compatible with Jupyter Notebook and can also be used on the Google Colab platform. You can access the script [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ZlanSUrOCbLW0mJgMsUDdV8bF4B0Ab66?usp=sharing).

The script also generates LaTeX source that can be used with `bussproofs.sty`.

It includes parser for propositional logic. So the following code generates (1) the LaTeX source and (2) the tree diagram.

```
input_formula = "not A imp B imp not C and D"
testParser(input_formula, 'bussproof')
testParser(input_formula, 'tree')
```

Generates the following LaTeX source

```
\begin{prooftree}
\AxiomC{$A$}
\UnaryInfC{$\neg$}
\AxiomC{$B$}
\AxiomC{$C$}
\UnaryInfC{$\neg$}
\AxiomC{$D$}
\BinaryInfC{$\wedge$}
\BinaryInfC{$\rightarrow$}
\BinaryInfC{$\rightarrow$}
\end{prooftree}
```

and the following diagram.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not a Jupyter Notebook user, but pretty sure you can do most or all of what you want with Graphviz.
Below are two examples, your original & one from "bussproofs.sty
A User Guide".
I'm not a logician, but automating individual cells looks pretty doable.  Depending on the input, automating the whole thing might not be too bad.
Each AST is created as a single "html-like" node label (https://graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html).
Some of the characters are incorrect, but that should be easy to fix.

```
graph B {
  rankdir=LR    // just for demo purposes

  { rank=same   // just for demo purposes  
  t1 [shape=plaintext,label=<
  <TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="2" BORDER="0">
  <TR>
    <TD BORDER="1" sides="b">A</TD>
    <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD BORDER="1" sides="b">B</TD>
    <TD BORDER="1" sides="b">&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD BORDER="1" sides="b">C</TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD BORDER="1" sides="b">&not;</TD>
    <TD BORDER="1" sides="b">&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD BORDER="1" sides="b">&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD BORDER="1" sides="b">&or;</TD>
    <TD BORDER="0">&nbsp;</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD >&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD>&rarr;</TD>
    <TD >&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD >&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD >&nbsp;</TD>
  </TR>  
  </TABLE>>]

  t2 [shape=plaintext,label=<
  <TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="2" BORDER="0">
  <TR>
    <TD BORDER="0" >&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD BORDER="0" >&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD BORDER="0" >&nbsp;</TD>    
    <TD BORDER="1" sides="b">&lfloor;A&rfloor;</TD>
    <TD BORDER="0">&nbsp;</TD>
  </TR>

  <TR>
    <TD BORDER="0" >&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD BORDER="0" >&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD BORDER="0" >&nbsp;</TD>    
    <TD BORDER="0" >&Pi;<sub>2</sub></TD>
    <TD BORDER="0">&nbsp;</TD>
  </TR>  
  <TR>
    <TD BORDER="0" >&Pi;<sub>1</sub></TD>
    <TD BORDER="0" >&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD BORDER="0" >&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD BORDER="1" sides="b">B</TD>
    <TD BORDER="0">&nbsp;</TD>
  </TR>
    <TR>
    <TD BORDER="1" sides="b">A</TD>
    <TD BORDER="1" sides="b">&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD BORDER="1" sides="b">A</TD>
    <TD BORDER="1" sides="b">&rarr;</TD>
    <TD BORDER="1" sides="b">B</TD>    
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD >&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD >B</TD>
    <TD >&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD >&nbsp;</TD>
  </TR>  
  </TABLE>
  >]
  }
  t1--t2  [style=invis]
}
```

Giving:
[image]

p.s. I like the keypunch - similar to IBM 026

Comment: Your code works beautifully in my VS Code Jupyter Notebook!

After I finish writing parsers for logical formulas and Fitch proof tree, I'll try to write a program that generates HTML source of the parsed AST.

Thanks so much!